# Mongodb one or two collection?

Tags: mysql, mongodb

I have a user database, and a web frontend, where people can register. I want to convert my mysql database to mongodb. In mysql I have a users table and same lookup tables like workplace types, address types, etc...
I read everywhere I can use nested documents (eg every users should have an embedded address_type table).

What if I have to list all available types on the website? I cant be sure, that all available types in the collection (eg I have 3 types and 100 users, 90 with type A, 10 with type B, but I have to give back all 3 types to the website).

In this case, should I have create separate collections for all mysql tables? What is the best practice in mongo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data modelling in MongoDB is much different from RDBMS. In mongodb, you need to analyze your data access pattern and out what piece of data are always accessed together in you application. In RDBMS, it is best practise to have data in 3rd normalized form, but in mongodb, as collection joins are discouraged, you should have embedded data. More details: [MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/)

If you are going to show all above user related information together most of the times, then yes, you should embed all that information together in one document. Because joining documents programmatically is going to be a very costly operation.

Comment: Thanks. If I embed the information, in the example above how can I get all types to feed my dropdown item? I have no type table/collection.

Comment: Well I can help you with query if you have structure in place. Right now that question is too broad to answer. Also before simply converting your mysql to mongodb, you need to evaluate if mongodb is really right choice for your application? I would suggest you should first read about nosql vs sql, then nosql CAP theory. If then mongodb turns out to be right choice, spend some time understanding data modeling in mongodb, as it is a very important factor for performance of your application.